# Table-of-contents with VIM folding

Tags: vim, folding

A long time ago there was an editor called MultiEdit. It has a feature which I can not find in all powerful VIM.  In MultiEdit I could press some hot key and it would show something like table-of-contents (aka, condensed-mode, aka outline) were I  could see only 1st line of all functions (let it be C source) in current file.  I could then move cursor to function that I need and after pressing enter, mode will switch to normal and  I would be in function that I need.  Very useful for those who likes to put many functions in one file.  This feature was extremely simple to use: one config option to enter regex for selecting title-lines and one hotkey for mode toggle.

VIM has folding. But this is different. Folding hides parts of files and displays folded-lines-indicator.  It is much more difficult to specify what to hide in folds for table-of-content-display: you need to start fold at title-line and end before next title line. This is more complex than simple regex to select titles.

I so much wanted this feature, I even wrote [VIM macro](https://gist.github.com/4554184) to emulate this MultiEdit behavior, even though I don't know VIM that much.  I've wrote it in part because it was easier to to learn a new language and write a macro than to figure out VIM folding module complexity. 
Unfortunately, after upgrading VIM, this macro now does not work (infinite loop?). I've wrote it long time ago, and what little I did know about VIM is all forgotten and I could not fix it now. (EDIT: I've fixed my script. Thanks to @romainl for the link).

My question is how to get this table-of-content like display in VIM?

Comment: if you want to get a function overview, did you think about the plugin taglist or tagbar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [recent vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/how-to-fold/) by Drew Neil explains the generalities of folding and [this one](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/writing-a-custom-fold-expression/) goes through the process of creating the kind of folding you are (probably) after.

Depending on the language you work with and your coding style, something as simple as

```
set foldmethod=marker
set foldmarker={,}
```

and `zM` can get you a long way:

[image: CSS folding]

If you want to customize what information is displayed, the second link above is almost certainly just what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at ctags and the vim plugin [tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/).

Comment: +1. Very cool plugin.  But I won't use it because I find it difficult to select an item without mouse.

Comment: You can use a mouse with tagbar if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

You also check out the vim plugin [unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) with the extension [Unite-Ouline](https://github.com/h1mesuke/unite-outline)
it gives a behavior quite close to what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

It's not great but have you tried `setlocal foldmethod=syntax`?  It seems to do a decent job in 7.3 on Windows.  ...although I just realized that our coding standard has the opening brace for a block at the end of the line rather than on a new line and if I change to having it on a new line it works substantially less well.

Comment: +1. I didn't know, very interesting. It does not work for me because it I have [custom C++ syntax file](http://github.com/lvv/syntax), which I need to update so it would work with folding.